# Play Framework - JPA nested transactions are not working

Tags: hibernate, jpa, playframework, transactions, playframework-2.0

I am using Play Framework 2.5.1 with javaJPA and it seems the nested transactions are not working as stated.

```
public TransactionEntity saveTransaction(TrasactionForm form) {
    return japApi.withTransaction(() -> { //outer transaction
        TransactionEntity t = jpaApi.withTransaction(() -> { //inner transaction
            TransactionEntity entity = form.toEntity();
            return txnDao.saveTransaction(entity);
        });
    return txnDao.getTransaction(entity.id); //should get the transaction from db, but throws exception saying no entity found
    });
}
```

The real case is little more complicated than the above-mentioned example. I have an outer transaction and saving an entity within a nested transaction and trying to fetch the just save transaction in the outer transaction - instead of fetching it, hibernate throwing entity not found the exception. The outer transaction is not able to see the inner transaction's writing to the DB.

If I debug Play JPA and hibernate code, everything works fine - is it because of the delay? I don't think that should happen as it is the basic transaction principle.

I read and looked at the code that Play now supports the nested transactions, but with my simple case, it is not working.

I appreciate any help and hints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're creating two transactions, but they're not "nested transactions" in the sense of having a parent and child transaction. [JPA doesn't support nested transactions](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Transactions#Nested_Transactions).

The two transactions are running concurrently (like if you'd created them in two separate threads) but are separate transactions. Whether one transaction will see the other one's committed values depends on the [database transaction isolation level](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19830-01/819-4721/beamv/index.html) and possibly any JPA caching. E.g. if you've already read a value in one transaction with JPA then it may be cached even if committed in another transaction.

If you want to read a committed value, then perhaps return it from the "inner" transaction code to the "outer" transaction as a normal Scala value. Alternatively you could run a third transaction to read the value.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. It is bit strange, it is working in few cases even when there is an outer transaction and failing in few cases - could not figure out the exact reason - It is mainly happening in test cases - I have some workarounds to avoid building Play app every time. Probably that could be the reason.

Comment: Depending on the transaction isolation level and underlying database I can imagine you could get non-deterministic results when reading rows.